# Check select box values and compare them with an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to check if a textfield, newTeamName is already in a list of teamnames stored in a select box. Unfortunately, my code does not work - what's wrong with it? Oh and I have no console problems.

```
    optionList = [];
    $('#chooseTeam option').each(function() {
        optionList.push($(this).val())
    });
    if (form.newTeamName.value in optionList) {
        $("#text-error").html("Team exists");
        $('#text-error').fadeIn(400).delay(3200).fadeOut(800);
        return false;
    }
```

Small Update:

Oh and my form.name.value's work fine as they work for other if statements.

Comment: FYI, you can create the option list using `.map`: `var optionList = $('#chooseTeam option').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

```
    $('#chooseTeam option').each(function() {
        if (form.newTeamName.value == $(this).val()){
            $("#text-error").html("Team exists");
            $('#text-error').fadeIn(400).delay(3200).fadeOut(800);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`optionList` is an array [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) used for object properties(or numeric array indices), you can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to test if a value is in an array

```
optionList = [];
$('#chooseTeam option').each(function() {
    optionList.push($(this).val())
});
if (optionList.indexOf(form.newTeamName.value) > -1) {
    $("#text-error").html("Team exists");
    $('#text-error').fadeIn(400).delay(3200).fadeOut(800);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
  my_array = Array();

  //To find if a value or element exists in an array
  if (my_array.indexOf(‘find_this_value’) != -1)
  {
        alert(‘Value exists in array.’);
  }

 //To find if a value or element DOES NOT exist in an array
 if (my_array.indexOf(‘find_this_value’) == -1)
 {
     alert(‘Value does not exist in array.’);
 }
```